# fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer() equivalent method in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, filereader, multer, pdf.js

I have a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object and I want to pass it to [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js)'s `getDocument` method. On the frontend I would use the `getDocument` method like so:

```
pdfjs.getDocument(fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(myFileHere))
```

How can I implement the above with [Node.js](http://www.nodejs.org)? I am also using [Express.js](http://expressjs.com) and [Multer](http://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: Are you sure PDF.js will even work in Node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea whether PDF.js is able to run on Node, but let's assume it is.

At least with the [`readFile`](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) (or [`readFileSync`](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) if you prefer to be obtaining the contents "immediately") procedure available in Node, files may be read into [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) objects, given the file's path.

If you take a look at the documentation of `Buffer` linked above, you'll also find specified that these are instances of [`UInt8Array`](http://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-49):

> The Buffer class is a subclass of JavaScript's Uint8Array class and extends it with methods that cover additional use cases.

Going further, an object of the `UInt8Array` class, also being an object of the [`TypedArray`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typedarray-objects) class (by the same specification that specifies the former), [has a property named `buffer`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-get-%typedarray%.prototype.buffer), which lets you access the, well, underlying buffer<sup>1</sup> that is... an [`ArrayBuffer`](http://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arraybuffer-objects)!

So, you should be able to use a variation on the following, to pass an `ArrayBuffer` with some file's contents to PDF.js:

```js
pdfjs.getDocument(require("fs").readFileSync("/path/to/file").buffer);
```

I have to assume you must read the file by path -- I assume your `fileReader` is a [`FileReader`](http://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader), which (contrary to its misleading name) reads `Blob` objects (and not files) -- *and Node does not have any `Blob` class defined!* So if you don't want to read the file by some path, then you'll have to tell us how you load file contents with Node at all.

<sup>1</sup> Don't blame me for the word "buffer" all over here, it's buffers all the way down, apparently -- I didn't design any of these classes ;)

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive explanation. I am using express' multer middleware to receive the form's PDF file. 
I assumed that the file object that multer passes is the same File/Blob object uploaded (like in the frontend). 
Finding hat the blob is not supported is unfortunate since I wanted to read it with pdfjs before proceeding to store it with multer.
In any case I will dig deeper in how can I approach it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found an npm package that apparently accomplishes this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/filereader

Comment: I don't see how that package you found is going to help you *in any way* with your problem -- if PDF.js works in Node, you just need to pass it some file's contents, like I explained in my answer above. The package simply abstracts what would be reading that same file you could read with `readFile` available with Node, into the `FileReader` API. In the end it will stand and fall on whether PDF.js can run on Node, and that alone. Whether Express.js is used is also of no consequence -- as it can't help you with your problem itself. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: I re-read your question, and it seems you want to use `getDocument` (on the backend) on files uploaded through the Web browser, correct?